# How to set a not plugged in pin to ground or Low

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

I have digital pin 7 when set to High it does and when set to low it does not.

The only way I can get consistent High or Low is to use a 2 position 3 pin switch with my pin 7 in the middle and ground on one side and 5v on the other.

Is there a way I can use an simple Open/Close switch and still get the same function?

As of not if I dont "pull" pin 7 to ground I get both open and close randomly.

Comment: Have you configured the pin as input? Please provide the code and your wiring diagram. A not connected pin, that is set as input, catches random noise, thus changes state rapidly.

Comment: Yes the pin is set to input, is there a way I can remake the circuit were it does not catch noise when it is open?

Comment: output+dwrite(low) doesn't ground it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you already found the solution. Without a pull-down of pull-up resistor, the voltage at pin 7 will float to some random voltage, when the switch is open.

Either add an (external) pull-down resistor. Or flip things around and use the **internal** pull-up resistor inside the ATMega328p. Then connect the other side of the switch to GND. Whenever the switch is pressed, your digitalWrite gives you a LOW.

To use the internal pull-up use `pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);`

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks for the advice it was super helpful.